# How do I edit an object if it exist or create an object that doesn't exist in Django?

Tags: python, django, generics, view, edit

I want to use a CreateView generic view to create an object if it doesn't exist, or edit it if it does. I use the kwargs['pk'] to catch a number from the url to find restaurant using the number as its ID. I use the request.user to find out which user is rating that restaurant. Right now a user can rate a restaurant he has rated before and can create a new record in the rating table every time he submits his rating. So far I have come up with the following.

## views.py

```
class Rate(CreateView):
    model = Rating
    success_url = "/first/restaurants/%(restaurant_id)s/"
    fields = ['rating']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(Rate, self).form_valid(form)
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/rate/$', views.Rate.as_view()),
```

## models.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    RESTAURANT_RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Poor'),
        (2, 'Unsatisfactory'),
        (3, 'Average'),
        (4, 'Good'),
        (5, 'Excellent'),
    )
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=3, choices=RESTAURANT_RATING_CHOICES)
```

I don't want to create a new record if a user is rating the SAME restaurant again. Instead I want to update his previous rating for that restaurant. I guess I have to write a custom get_object() method for my CreateView class or something like using get_or_create(). I dunno, I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `update_or_create` method (described here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

Something like this:

```
defaults = {'rating': 5}
Rating.objects.update_or_create(restaurant_id=1, user_id=1, defaults=defaults)
```

If rating object in this restaurant does not exists, it will create it. If exists, rating will be updated.

Note: this method is new in django 1.7

Comment: How do I implement this within my CreateView class? Or do I need to just create a normal view?

Comment: If you have no strong reasons to use generic views, you can write your own view. But if you want to use generic, you may to override `ProcessFormView.post` (`CreateView` is a subclass of `ProcessFormView`) to handle object creation in your way.

Comment: I guess this is one of those situations where a generic view needs more coding than a custom view. I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you coldmind. I was finally able to make it work. Used your code above instead of form.save(). Cheers.